# Tables and flushright Environment: Extending beyond margin

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table of width `\textwidth` in the `tabularx` environment.
The problem is, that it frustratingly extends beyond the margin, if not corrected with `flushleft`.

The next line (`Bonn, \today`) also extends beyond the margin (edit: or just beyond the table?), something that I cannot fix with `flushleft`, as it is already in the `flushright` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
ragged2e,
tabularx,
geometry,
}

%%% GEOMETRY %%%
\geometry{
    a4paper,%210mm, 297mm
    total={170mm,257mm},
    showframe,
}

%---%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

%---%

\fontsize{2.5mm}{1mm}\selectfont
%\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{ 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X  }
Zelle 1a & Zelle 1b\\ 
Zelle 2a & Zelle 2b\\ 
Zelle 3a & Zelle 3b\\ 
Zelle 4a & Zelle 4b\\
Zelle 5a & Zelle 5b\\
\end{tabularx}
%\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
Bonn, \today
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

In the following pictures, I have enabled the `showframe` option of the geometry package.

**With flushleft environment**
[image: flushleft environment]

**Without flushleft environment**
[image: without flushleft environment]

*please excuse the black borders.*

Comment: unrelated but `\fontsize{2.5mm}{1mm}\selectfont` is specifying a font 2 and a half times bigger than the baseline spacing, that is not achievable and will produce very inconsistent line spacing

Comment: without `flushleft` you are indenting it by the paragraph indent which is normally 15pt so it goes over-full, precede by `\noindent`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, but `flushright` should ignore that. Tables shouldn't be affected by that either, right? -- And the fontsize command is something I have taken from somewhere and just kept the ratio. What's the correct way?

Comment: @Concerto: Probably `\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{ @{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X  @{}}` results in the expected output?

Comment: Oh yes, so tables are affected by it! There is a space between the « b » and the edge of the margin, in a way, that the « 2020 » doesn't align with the « b's ».

Comment: @Concerto: Did you notice the two `@{}` I added to your code? With them, I removed the small horizontal white space that is added to the left and right of a text in a table cell. (`\tabcolsep`, its default value is 6pt). You can easily spot the difference if you temporarily add a vertical line to your table code. Compare the results of `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X |}` and `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |@{}  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}| }`.

Comment: @leandriis I apologise, I didn't notice them. This, however, solves my question. Thank you so much. Would you like to transfer that to an answer?

Comment: flushright sets `\parindent` to 0pt so it is still technically indented but has no visible effect. You should almost never need to use `\fontsize` in a document,  what is the intention?  normally `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever is used. (especially specifying font sizes in mm is somewhat  unconventional)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, for some of my fonts, I need the `\fontsize` command, as `\small` or `\Huge` don't reach the desired effect. Why is mm unconventional? I can imagine better on the page, also, consistency.

Comment: I wouldn't have mentioned the units if that was all, but 2.5mm high letters on lines 1mm apart doesn't really work:-) fonts are usually specified in pt but not for any real reason. and fixed font sizes are usually to be avoided in generic classes like `article` as for example adding `[12pt]` makes the `\small` and `\normalsize` bigger  but 2.5mm is 2.5mm so it is losing some flexibility (of course you may know your document doesn't need to have generic styling in that sense, but people copy all kinds of things off examples on the internet so if in doubt it's best to query such use:-)

Comment: ideally rather than using fixed sizes mid document you would _define_ the names like `\small` and `\large` to be the sizes that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\noindent` right before `\begin{tabularx}` to remove the paragraph indentation and add `@{}` before the first and after the last column specifier to get rid of the padding (`\tabcolsep`, usually 6pt) that is added at both sides of the text in a table cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
ragged2e,
tabularx,
geometry,
}

%%% GEOMETRY %%%
\geometry{
    a4paper,%210mm, 297mm
    total={170mm,257mm},
    showframe,
}

%---%

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{ @{}
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{} }
Zelle 1a & Zelle 1b\\ 
Zelle 2a & Zelle 2b\\ 
Zelle 3a & Zelle 3b\\ 
Zelle 4a & Zelle 4b\\
Zelle 5a & Zelle 5b\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{flushright}
Bonn, \today
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```